# How to embed power bi report in java web application?

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I have a log analysis tool as a Java based web application with html/jsp front end. Java backend receives real-time log data from few different agents/datasources and does ML/analysis and then stores insights on a file system, accessible only to Java backend. Now my users login to the system using a browser and access Java backend and insights using rest endpoints in the form of HTML/jsp reports/dashboards.

All sounds good but my users are complaining that UI is not production grade. So I am searching for different solutions to build a nicer UI experience for my users and I am looking into Power BI embedded solution.

How to integrate power bi embedded to serve insights that continuously change behind the scenes? how does it work in this use case knowing that my insights are only accessible to my Java backend and can only be served using Rest End points?

Also are there any better alternative solutions?

Comment: you can start here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-analytics-power-bi

Comment: @LevGelman I did look at that. What is not clear to me is, how does report/power bi receive real time insights which is only accessible to Java backend.

Comment: You can use your API as a source for PowerBI, or to save your application data in some database/files and give PowerBI access to it.